# Matching timestamps in two dataframes using dplyr

Tags: r, timestamp, tidyverse, dplyr

So I have a dataframe like this

**DF1**

```
ID    timestamp              value
1     2018-07-31 20:00:00    45555
1     2018-08-01 06:50:00    333
1     2018-08-01 07:00:00    322
2     2018-08-01 13:00:00    1222
2     2018-08-01 22:00:00    1111
3     2018-08-01 11:00:00    0
3     2018-08-02 08:00:00    22222
```

And another one like this

**DF2**

```
          startTime             endTime   ID    
2018-08-01 06:45:00 2018-08-01 09:49:00   1
2019-12-02 11:01:00 2019-12-02 11:02:00   2
2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00   2
2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00   3
```

So I want to create a new column using `mutate` which mutates **DF2** that tells me if any time in between the `startTime` and `endTime`  appears in **DF1** that matches the ID.

So in **DF2** if we have a date like 8/2/2018 and the time span is 7:59AM - 8:50AM , if any timestamp within this interval inclusive (2018-08-02 7:59:00, 2018-08-02 8:00:00, 2018-08-02 8:01:00...) appears in **DF1** then a variable in **DF2** reads 1, else 0. This is only the case if the `ID` matches. Does not matter how many times, atleast once is what matters.

Final version of **DF2** should look like.

```
          startTime             endTime   ID   match
2018-08-01 06:45:00 2018-08-01 09:49:00   1    1
2019-12-02 11:01:00 2019-12-02 11:02:00   2    0
2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00   2    0
2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00   3    1
```

Ideally I would like to use `BETWEEN()` and remain in the tidyverse.

Comment: Are the ddate time columnsof correct date time class

Comment: yup, they match @akrun

Comment: I think this can be better solved in data.table i.e. more efficiently

Comment: DF1 is a postgresql database btw; and both classes are POSIXct btw.

Comment: @akrun mutate is what makes sense to me but if you see a better alternative I'm open to suggestions

Comment: if it is a database, then I am not sure whether all the tidyverse functions work on it.  You could use sql commands

Comment: @akrun i can pipe from it as if it is a dataframe no problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use a `data.table` non-equi join on the DateTime columns along with 'ID' column, create the `match` by checking if the number of rows (`.N`) is greater than 0

```
library(data.table)
DF2$match <- 0L
setDT(DF2)[DF1,  match := +(.N > 0),on = .(ID, 
        startTime < timestamp, endTime > timestamp), by = .EACHI]
DF2
#             startTime             endTime ID match
#1: 2018-08-01 06:45:00 2018-08-01 09:49:00  1     1
#2: 2019-12-02 11:01:00 2019-12-02 11:02:00  2     0
#3: 2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00  2     0
#4: 2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00  3     1
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
 timestamp = structure(c(1533085200, 
1533124200, 1533124800, 1533146400, 1533178800, 1533139200, 1533214800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(45555L, 
333L, 322L, 1222L, 1111L, 0L, 22222L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L
), class = "data.frame")

DF2 <- structure(list(startTime = structure(c(1533123900, 1575306060, 
1533214740, 1533214740), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    endTime = structure(c(1533134940, 1575306120, 1533217800, 
    1533217800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your request for a tidyverse solution, you can also do this by first joining the two dfs by 'ID', then using lubridate's `%within%` and `interval` (`%--%`) functions to find matches:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df_both <- left_join(DF2, DF1, by = "ID") 

df_both %>%
  group_by(ID, startTime, endTime) %>%
  summarize(match = any(timestamp %within% (startTime %--% endTime)),
            .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      ID startTime           endTime             match
#>   <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>
#> 1     1 2018-08-01 06:45:00 2018-08-01 09:49:00 TRUE 
#> 2     2 2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00 FALSE
#> 3     2 2019-12-02 12:01:00 2019-12-02 12:02:00 FALSE
#> 4     3 2018-08-02 07:59:00 2018-08-02 08:50:00 TRUE
```

If you prefer 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE, you can use `as.integer` to convert the 'match' column as such.